# javascript cookies, setting multiple cookies

Tags: javascript, cookiestore

I'm trying to create an application, that takes in multiple values with cookies, however it seems my setCookie function is not taking in multiple, but instead replacing each value when I enter a new one, so the showCookie functions only displays last value entered.

setCookie:

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

storeValues function:

```
function storeValues()  
{
var note= document.getElementById("note").value;



 setCookie("note",note,365);


 alert("Cookies stored!")

 }
```

show functions:

```
function show()
{
 var note= document.getElementById("note").value;


 alert("Note:" + note  );

}

function showall()
{
var allcookies = document.cookie;
 alert("All Cookies : " + allcookies );

// Get all the cookies pairs in an array
cookiearray  = allcookies.split(';');

// Now take key value pair out of this array
for(var i=0; i<cookiearray.length; i++){
  name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
  value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
  alert("Key is : " + name + " and Value is : " + value);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change from assignment operator (`=`) to concatenation and assignment compound operator (`+=`).

It would also be a good idea to overwrite the cookie key if it exists. So I'd recommend turning the cookie values into an object, modifying them and then serialising back to a cookie string.

Comment: Hmm not sure what all that means. Is it the operators in the setCookie?

Comment: Thank You! It works-ish. I need to do some tweaking. I have a delete function, however it only deletes the value just entered                                 `function deleteallcookies()  
{  
var cookie = document.cookie;  
var arr = cookie.split("; ");  
var i;  
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)  
 {  
       temp = arr[i].split("=");  
       setCookie(temp[0]);  
   }  
  
  
  checkCookie();
  
 alert("Deleted");  
}`